# "Operation must be updateable query" on UPDATE with JOIN to GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on my A2 coursework, where we're using access to create a database management system. For part of my system, I have a query which counts how many items a user has rented within a given time period. Now, I need to update this value and insert it into the users table.

In the Users Table, there is a field called "GamesRentedThisMonth". I've made a query which calculated this value. I've set up relationships of the query to link the UserID to the User table.

```
UPDATE Users INNER JOIN UserGamesRentedThisMonth ON (Users.ID = UserGamesRentedThisMonth.UserID)
SET Users.GamesRentedThisMonth = UserGamesRentedThisMonth.CountOfOrderID
```

Design view:
[image]

I've even tried to check the query:

```
UPDATE Users INNER JOIN UserGamesRentedThisMonth ON (Users.ID = UserGamesRentedThisMonth.UserID) SET Users.GamesRentedThisMonth = 5;
```

which still yields the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases there's no getting around creating a temporary table as GavinP describes in his answer, but Access supports "Domain Aggregate Functions" which can often be used to work around the issue. In your case you could use the `DLookUp()` function this way:

```sql
UPDATE Users SET 
    GamesRentedThisMonth = DLookUp("CountOfOrderID", "UserGamesRentedThisMonth", "UserID=" & ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a summarising query within an update in Access. It's a pain. This has been the case since JET 4 unfortunately. The "usual" method to avoid this is to create a temp table with the summed values first, then use that in the join to the destination update query. In your case something like making UserGamesRentedThisMonth query into a make table query creating tblTemp and changing your original query to

```
UPDATE Users INNER JOIN tblTemp ON (Users.ID = tblTemp.UserID)
SET Users.GamesRentedThisMonth = tblTemp.CountOfOrderID
```

Hope that helps.